# Can this C/C++ if() statement ever evaluate to TRUE?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

According to **PC-lint**, the following statement will never be `TRUE`:

```
if((variable & 0x02) == 1)
```

I am using a C compiler for embedded systems that evaluates it to `TRUE` whenever the corresponding bit in `variable` is set. I guess the compiler is doing a `TRUE`/`FALSE` comparison of both sides of the `==` instead of comparing the resulting numbers. In other words, every time the expression `(varable & 0x02)` is not zero (i.e. `TRUE`), the statement will also be `TRUE`, since the value `1  is also  TRUE` (not zero).

I don't know if the `C/C++` standards clearly define how a compiler should behave in this case. Are there any `C/C++` experts out there who can answer this question based on what the standards (e.g. `C90, C99,` etc.) say?

P.S.: In the statement above, "variable" is an unsigned char.

Comment: Could you please name this compiler? A friend of mine makes a collection of odd compiler bugs.

Comment: Is it possible that your real code has a double ampersand (e.g. "var && 0x02")? That would explain the compiler evaluating it as true.

Comment: @tinman good guess, this moves error from compiler to program code :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PC-lint is right. Assuming `var` is an integer variable, the expression `var & 0x02` can evaluate to two values: `0` and `2`. It will never be equal to `1`, which is what the `if` statement is testing.

To expand on this, the equality operator is being applied to two integer values. What matters is whether both operands evaluate to the same number, not whether they're both simultaneously "true" or "false".

To test whether bit 1 is set, one could use:

```
if (variable & 0x02) {
  ...
}
```

Given that your compiler behaves the way you say it does, it's clearly non-compliant. However, it will almost certainly handle `if (variable & 0x02)` correctly. My recommendation would be to fix the code so it won't break silently if you were ever to change compilers.

Finally, the situation is different if: (1) the code is C++ and not C; and (2) `variable` is instance of a class; and (3) the class overloads the operators in question. In that case, the behaviour is down to what the overloaded operators actually do.

Comment: This is because `0x02` has just a single bit set in its bit pattern.

Comment: This is not the case in C++ due to the presence of overloaded operators.

Comment: Ideally you should always use the pattern `if ((variable & CONST) == CONST)` if you want to check to see if all the bits in a given mask are set.

Comment: This is surely one way to view it. But my question was "what do the standards say about it?".

Comment: @bdonlan: True, but to quote the OP: "I am using a C compiler...", so I think it's safe to assume that `variable` is of a type that's available in both C and C++.

Comment: @aix he tagged and asked for information on both C and C++ \*shrug\*

Comment: "My recommendation would be to fix the code..." The code is correct.  If he actually has a compiler which gets this wrong (which I seriously doubt), then my recommendation would be to change the compiler; a compiler which gets this wrong probably gets a lot of other things wrong, and is certainly so broken as to not be usable.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, this can evaluate to a true value if (and only if) `variable` is an instance of a class with an overloaded `operator&` which does not conform to normal bitwise AND semantics.

In C, this condition will always be false. §6.5.10 defines the semantics of the bitwise AND operator, and it's quite simple and to the point:

> 4. The result of the binary & operator is the bitwise AND of the operands (that is, each bit in
>   the result is set if and only if each of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is
>   set).

It's clear that the result cannot be 1, as the 1 bit is not set in the converted value of the right-hand-side operand (namely, `0x02`).

Naturally, if undefined behavior has been invoked at some point in the program's past (or at compile time!), then anything can happen. Barring this possibility, however, your compiler is non-compliant. That is to say, broken. This, unfortunately, is *extremely* common on odd embedded compilers. If you're lucky, you may even be able to report the bug and get it fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the standard defines anything about this very specific and unusual issue. As said by aix, that statement can never be true because (in binary):

```
XXXX XXXX -> variable
0000 0010 -> 0x02
--------- AND
0000 00X0 -> result
```

(simplifying to 8-bit types)

So your only results can be 0000 0010 (which is 2) or 0000 0000 (which is 0).

Answer (score 1):

For C, the answer is no.

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) says about `&` (6.5.10):

> The result of the binary & operator is the bitwise AND of the operands (that is, each bit in
>   the result is set if and only if each of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is
>   set).

Since in `2` only the bit 1 is set, the value of the expression can only have set the bit 1. It can take no other values than 2 and 0. Neither 2 nor 0 can compare equal to 1.

The bit representations of integers are defined in 6.2.6.2 (for non-negative values in the usual way).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, lint is right here. At least on any platform I know of, the condition will yield false. Look at the bit representation of the numbers: x & 2 (0010) will always be either zero or 2 (0010) and thus different from 1 (0001) for any integer x.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the binary value of 2

```
  02 = 0010 (say a 4 bit number)
```

and the binary value of 1 is

```
  01 = 0001
```

The least significat bit of 2 is always  zero that is the left most bit is 0. SO
The & (and) operation with 0 never gives 1 hence we can say it can never be equal to 1

```
      0 0 =>    0
      0 1 =>    0
      1 1 =>    1
```

Note: & indicates the bit wise and operation

```
   2 - 0010
   3 - 0011
       0010
```

So the output with xx & 2 will be 0 or 2.